# Word Macro to Convert Text into Hyperlinks

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have about 400 links throughout the end notes section of my word document. However, the links are just regular text, and are not hyperlinked to the URL.

Here is an example of a citation in my end notes:

Odgerel Tseveen, Ganbold Battsetseg, & Badmaarag Shagdarsuren. The Mongolian Legal System and Laws: a Brief Overview. Hauser Global Law School Program, New York University. May 2009. http://www.nyulawglobal.org/globalex/Mongolia1.htm

If I place my cursor at the end of the link and press the space bar, then the link becomes active.

I would like to automate the process by creating a macro that will recognize the links without me having to create a space after every single one.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub EndsToHLink()
    Dim eNote As Endnote
    Dim iFound As Integer
    Dim rLink As Range
    Dim iDot As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each eNote In ActiveDocument.Endnotes
        'eNote.Range.Text = eNote.Range.Text & " "
        iFound = InStr(eNote.Range.Text, "http")
        iDot = 0
        If iFound > 0 Then
            If Right(eNote.Range.Text, 1) = "." Then iDot = 1
            Set rLink = eNote.Range
            rLink.SetRange Start:=eNote.Range.Start + iFound - 1, End:=eNote.Range.End - iDot
            rLink.Hyperlinks.Add rLink, rLink.Text
        End If

    Next eNote
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

You'll need to test it first!

Comment: good attempt for a +1 from me...

Answer (score 0):

Adding a space doesn't really work programmatically. The following converts the end notes into hyperlinks.

```
Sub EndsToHLink()
    Dim eNote As Endnote

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each eNote In ActiveDocument.Endnotes
        'eNote.Range.Text = eNote.Range.Text & " "
        eNote.Range.Hyperlinks.Add eNote.Range, "http://" & eNote.Range.Text
    Next eNote
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks andrew. Interesting approach. I think i need to be a little clearer in my question because the references aren't just the links, there is other text in there too. They look like this: Odgerel Tseveen, Ganbold Battsetseg, & Badmaarag Shagdarsuren. The Mongolian Legal System and Laws: a Brief Overview. Hauser Global Law School Program, New York University. May 2009. http://www.nyulawglobal.org/globalex/Mongolia1.htm

Comment: It is more complicated then. You'll need to examine eNote.Range (perhaps using .Range.Find), find "http", read from here to the end of the note, converting just this part to a hyperlink. If the link is always at the very end of each footnote then this task is a little easier - you just need to convert the last word to a link.

Comment: yes, the link is always the last word. sometimes there is a . at the end after the link though. how would i go about reading to the end of the note?